# Photoshop Installation in 10.10

Tags: photoshop

Hi all I am new to ubuntu using ver 10.10 anyone tell me how to install the photoshop using terminal.

I tried googling all result yields to install wine

So I open the ubuntu software center and type wine
but its display untrusted service package(While Installation).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply is ubuntu issues or that wine s/w has need required version ?

Comment: @vicky There's absolutely no excuse for **starting** with Ubuntu using an old unsupported version. Just upgrade. Then use the search to find other questions regarding running Photoshop on Ubuntu. There are **tons** of them.

Comment: Whether If i loss anyother data or file while upgrade .. Pls tell me i really confuse what going to  ..

Comment: As stated 10.10 is not supported.  When running PS in Wine it also make a difference what version you have: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17 . CS5 would appear to be the best option, however CS6 might be usable.  Running windows on a virtual machine like VirtualBox might also be an option.

Comment: @jorge ,@Eliah ,@gertvdijk,@fossfreedom Photoshop installation is for ubuntu ver 10.10 not its the duplicate

Comment: @Fresher stop rolling back. It is a duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wine is a free software, developed for executing Microsoft Windows applications on Linux based operating systems and OSX. Basically Windows software cannot be used in Ubuntu because Ubuntu uses **.deb** files unlike Windows that uses **.exe** file.

To install WINE in Ubuntu 10.10, 1st open up the TERMINAL (ctrl + alt + t) then type one by one -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.4
```

Enter your password if prompted. Currently wine 1.4 is the latest stable version

There you go. It will finish up in no time and you can directly install Photoshop in Ubuntu afterwards by double clicking the **setup** icon of **PHOTOSHOP**. Or right click on setup icon and open with WINE.

If you are interested -[WINE WEBSITE](http://www.winehq.org/) [Source](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/03/install-wine-1.html) [If you want to use synaptic package manager](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/01/27/installing-wine-on-ubuntu-10-10/)

One more thing if you think you can work on an alternative rather then to use Photoshop. Please give **GIMP** a try. You will find it in Ubuntu Software Center. Good luck.

Comment: see when i type this command in terminal i get Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 883E8688397576B6C509DF495A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
gpg: requesting key F9CB8DB0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection timed out
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install wine`

Comment: installation is in progress will inform after finish and also how to install the photoshop

Comment: Once u finish installing the WINE. You can install photoshop as u do in windows os(double clicking the icon). Or rightclick on the **setup** and openwith WINE. One thing more listen do what they told you about upgrading your OS. Or you are certain to face issues.

Comment: sorry i get this error       E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
I tried sudo apt-get update still same

Comment: run `sudo apt-get update` (it will update the package lists) 1st and then `sudo apt-get install wine` (to install it)

Comment: even i did by your following sugges still same error message happen  E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6825/discussion-between-vicky-and-arin-chakraborty)

Comment: @vicky Again... 10.10 is unsupported now. Archives don't have packages for 10.10 anymore, only upgrade support.

Comment: thanks Whether If i loss anyother data or file while upgrade ..

Comment: @vicky In spite of what some people say, **there absolutely *are* still archives available for end-of-life Ubuntu releases like 10.10**. See [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/22949) However: (1) You should not use an unsupported release. There is no reason to do so, you'll have lots of problems, and there are very limited resources available for help. (2) Unsupported releases don't get any new updates. Using an unsupported release is dangerous because **when security bugs are discovered, they are not fixed in unsupported releases**.